# How to bind DataTable with different combobox items each row to DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I created a general DataTable like this, it's fine :

```cs
    BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
    bindingSource1.DataSource = CreateDataTable();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

    private DataTable CreateDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("String1"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("String2"));
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); dr["String1"] = "a"; dr["String2"] = "aa"; dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                dr = dt.NewRow(); dr["String1"] = "b"; dr["String2"] = "bb"; dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        //...
        return dt;
    }
```

But I need a comboBoxColumn which has different datasource each row in datatablegrid, so I refer to some solutions tried to set Columns and DataSource to datagridview :

```cs
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("String1", "String1");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("String2", "String2");
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    comboCol.HeaderText = comboCol.DataPropertyName = comboCol.Name= "combo1";// fixed by ConnorTJ
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboCol);
    
    bindingSource1.DataSource = CreateDataTable();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
    
    Dictionary<int, List<string> > comboDic = new Dictionary<int, List<string> >() {
    { 0, new List<string>() { "1", "11", "111" } },
    { 1, new List<string>() { "2", "22", "222" } } };
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["combo1"];
        comboCell.DataSource = comboDic[i];
        //comboCell.Value = "n";//set the value out of items will throw error
    }
```

Now the string columns are empty, So how exactly should it be achieved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load different data into different rows of the same comboboxcolumn c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67938153/load-different-data-into-different-rows-of-the-same-comboboxcolumn-c-sharp)

Comment: @JohnG I have read many answers, they usually talk about one aspect. I haven't seen a workable solution for having both **datatable** and **comboColumn** in one datagridview, and the comboboxColumn with **different items** is only part of the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are not making it clear what “aspect” you are having an issue with. If a _”comboboxColumn with different items is only part of the question”_ … then, what is the other part of the question? IMO, the problem most people have in relation to doing this is that there are kind of like two (2) `DataSources` for the combo boxes… 1) is a `DataSource` for the “COLUMN” which contains ALL the items from ALL the individual combo boxes… then, 2) each combo box has its own `DataSource` which is a “subset/filtered” version of the items in the “columns” data source.

Comment: What part of my previous link is missing or not helping in understanding how to implement different values in the same combo box column?

Comment: @JohnG Thank you still for your answer. My previous confusion was combining datatable and comboboxcolumn, as to different rows have their own datasource I actually used a dictionary to implement it in my code (seems ok, but it's a part of the comboboxColumn demand so I mention it). Now I know what my problem is add two new columns in datagridview, just delete them and recover AutoGenerateColumns as true.

Comment: If you have it working as you want then that is great. I am still not understanding how the GRIDS `DataSource` is connected to the combo box column. In the posted code, the combo box column appears completely independent and detached from the grids `DataSource`. Example, the line of code… `comboCol.HeaderText = comboCol.DataPropertyName = comboCol.Name= "combo1";` … is somewhat odd in a sense that setting the combo box columns `DataPropertyName` is meaningless since the grids `DataTable` has NO column named `combo1`.

Comment: This is irrelevant if your intention is to have the combo box column detached from the grids data source. Glad you got it working.

Comment: @JohnG Actually... I hadn't used 'DataPropertyName' attribute before until you mentioned it, I just assigned it as some kind of place name. So now I found another solution for the previous case. This has given me a lot of new ideas ( And it make the comboboxColumn datasource more complicated, hah )

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the actual Columns `Name` property, you have set the `DataPropertyName` property

Once you set the `comboCol.Name` property, when doing:

```
var comboCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
            {
                HeaderText = "combo1",
                DataPropertyName = "combo1",
                Name = "combo1"
            };
```

You can then do:

```
var comboCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[comboCol.Name];
comboCell.DataSource = comboDic[i];
comboCell.Value = "n";
```

Added note: You can also use the `comboCol.Index` property too which will give you the Column Index.

Comment: Oh... it was a cheap mistake. On the other hand , I know how to deal with it now, just don't add new textboxcolumns in to datagridview.