# How can I fill a Combobox in a datagridview in Windows Form application using C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have populated a Data Grid view dgvSystem from database using C# code.
I have 10 rows and 6 columns  in my Data Grid view dgvSystem, in this dgvsystem column 2,3,4,5 are check boxes and column 6 is a combobox (dropdown).
Combo box for column 6 has to be filled dynamically from database table based on the value of coulmn 1. I am not able to figure out the code for this as I am new to windows form.
If someone can help me to write the code to populate the drop down after the data grid is created with drop down.
I want to populate this combo boxes at runtime using C# code. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, you question is vague and it is unclear what issue you may be having. There are many examples of how to fill a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` with items for the combo boxes. What part of this is not working for you or you do not understand? You state that the… _"Combo box for column 6 has to be filled dynamically from database table based on the value of coulmn 1"_ … I assume this means that each combo box on each row in the grid has possibly “different” values? This is doable; however it can be tricky and frustrating if done in the wrong way.

Comment: Typically, is what you would do is give the combo box “COLUMN” a `DataSource` that contains ALL the different values for all the combo boxes, then when each combo box is clicked on, the code would set that combo boxes data source based on the values in column 1. This data source for the individual combo box cell would simply be a “subset” of the “COLUMNS” `DataSource`. I have a rather long answer that does this using a banks and branches scenario but it explains the problems associated with having the combo boxes contain different values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load different data into different rows of the same comboboxcolumn c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67938153/load-different-data-into-different-rows-of-the-same-comboboxcolumn-c-sharp)